# itunes connect not showing user ratings and reviews

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store-connect, review

So I released my first game on the Apple App Store a couple of weeks ago. I've been keeping track on user ratings and review in iTunes Connect from the 'My Apps' -> 'Activity' --> 'Ratings and Reviews'. It has been working as it should since the release, up until yesterday. I can't choose the app store country or see any ratings or reviews. It says: No Ratings and Reviews Data. Is anyone getting this right now, or is this normal from time to time maybe? I haven't changed any settings or such. So that shouldn't be it.

So [this is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVvun.png) on iTunes Connect.

So any help would be appreciated. Or tips. Hints. Anything. I know I can use platforms like Sensor Tower, but still, I like checking it out on iTunes Connect.

All the best, 
/Sebastian

Comment: Yes, the same thing is happening to me. It must be a bug on Apple's end. It looks like they recently changed the user interface for reviews, and it's not quite working properly yet.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: I have the issue. Can't check the ratings of my apps since weeks now :(

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Yeah, it seems to be a bug then.

Answer (score 1):

It's not you. When they changed the design of that part of iTunes connect a while ago, the ratings and reviews page stopped loading for at least one of my apps (rotating circle nothing else), then, about 2 weeks ago it started loading but it would show empty/broken like the image you posted. Then, a week ago the other apps that had been showing reviews up to that point started coming up the same way. I have sent a customer support message with a screenshot, but I haven't heard back from Apple.

I've had more problems since the last redesign, like long (or sometimes seemingly infinite) redirection loops when trying to login after I am logged-out (interestingly it mostly affects Safari), but the ratings/reviews issue that seems to get worse (spreading to more apps) is definitely the most severe issue.

Comment: Alright, good to know. Thank you for the answer. I also get stuck on the loading page too often. 

I did get an answer from Apple but it was more of a "try this before I report the issue to our systems team for assistance". Reset browser, try another browser etc. 

So I guess we have to wait and see. 

Cheers!

Comment: Yeah, the loading issues appear on all browsers intermittently, it is quite obvious it is Apple's fault, but they are always into denial.
In the meantime, a few hours after I posted the above, I got contacted by Apple and after I sent them more info they told me they opened a ticket for this and gave me a reference number. So, that was Nov 26th, haven't heard back since, and the problem is of course not fixed...

Comment: It is now fixed for me.